# Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$, show that there exists unique partial isometry $V$ such that $A=VP$ for some positive $P$ and rank$(A)=$rank$(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, isometry

First I have shown the existence. Define $P:=\sqrt{A^*A}$. Then it's easy to verify that $\lVert Pv\rVert=\lVert Av\rVert$ for all $v\in\Bbb{C}^n$.

We have $\Bbb{C}^n=Ran(P)\oplus Ran(P)^{\perp}=Ran(P)\oplus Ker(P)$ (as $P^*=P$), define $V$ as follows $$V(x+y)=Tx\ \text{where } x\in Ran(P),y\in Ker(P)$$

$V$ is well defined follows from the fact $\lVert Pv\rVert=\lVert Av\rVert$ for all $v\in\Bbb{C}^n$. It can be shown that $Ker(V)=Ker(P)$ and $V$ is partial isometry.

Now, $Ker(P)=Ker(\sqrt{A^*A})=Ker(A^*A)=Ker(A)$. This proves the existence.

But I am stuck with the uniqueness of $V$ part. If we have $A=WQ$ where $W$ is partial isometry and $Q$ is positive such that rank$(A)=$rank$(W)$ then we need to prove $W=V$. As we have $Ran(A)\subseteq Ran(W)$ and their dimensions are given to be same then $Ran(A)=Ran(W)$.

I can prove the uniqueness if $Ker(Q)=Ker(W)$, which is exactly the statement of Polar Decomposition Theorem. But how to prove the existance of partial isometry $V$ in this case **rank$(A)=$rank$(W)$**.

Can anyone give me a wayout? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: When I have $T=WQ$ for partial isometry $W$ and positive $Q$. I can say that $W$ is isometry on $Ker(W)^{\perp}$ which is contained in $Ker(Q)^{\perp}=Ran(Q)$. If I don't have the condition $Ker(W)=Ker(Q)$, then how to tell $W$ is isometry on $Ran(Q)$?

Comment: You cannot expect that $W$ is an isometry on ${\rm Im}\,Q$ in general. For example if $A$ is itself a singular partial isometry then we can take $W=A$ and $Q=I.$  I can show that $WW^*$ is uniquely determined. The condition $A=WQ$ and ${\rm rank}\,A={\rm rank }\,W$ implies ${\rm Im}\, A={\rm Im}\, W.$ In general  $U$ is a partial isometry if and only if $UU^*$ is the orthogonal projection from $(\ker U^*)^\perp={\rm Im}\, U$ onto itself. We have $WW^*$ is a projection from
$(\ker W^*)^\perp={\rm Im}\, W={\rm Im}\, A,$ onto itself. Hence $WW^*$ is uniquely determined by $A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider $\mathbb{C}^2.$ For fixed unit vectors $u,v$ let $Wx=\langle x,u\rangle v.$ Then $W$ is a partial isometry. For an arbitrary nonnegative operator $Q,$ such that $Qu\neq 0,$ let $A=WQ$. Hence
$$Ax=WQx=\langle Qx,u\rangle v=\langle x, Qu\rangle v$$

Now we determine the standard polar decomposition of $A,$ i.e. $A=V|A|,$ where $V$ is the partial isometry from ${\rm Im}\,|A|$ onto ${\rm Im}\,A.$ We have
$$A^*x=\langle x,v\rangle Qu$$
Hence $$A^*Ax=\langle x, Qu\rangle Qu,\quad |A|x={1\over \|Qu\|}\langle x,Qu\rangle Qu$$
The partial isometry $V$ satisfies
$V|A|x=Ax .$ For $x=Qu$ we get $|A|Qu=\|Qu\|\,Qu$ and $AQu=\|Qu\|^2\,v.$ Hence
$$ VQu=\|Qu\|\,v $$ On the other hand
$$WQu= \langle Qu,u\rangle v$$
Thus $W\neq V$ provided that $$\langle Qu,u\rangle \neq \|Qu\|$$
Now we are ready to construct an adequate example.
Let $$u=v=\begin{pmatrix} {\sqrt{3}\over 2}\\ {1\over 2}\end{pmatrix},\qquad Q=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$W=\begin{pmatrix} {3\over 4} &{\sqrt{3}\over 4}\\
{\sqrt{3}\over 4} &{1\over 4}
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
A=\begin{pmatrix} {3\over 4} & 0\\
{\sqrt{3}\over 4}& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Moreover
$$V=\begin{pmatrix}
{\sqrt{3}\over 2} & 0\\
{1\over 2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}\qquad |A|=\begin{pmatrix}
{\sqrt{3}\over 2} & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
All the operators showing up in the example have rank $1.$

**Remark**
If we assume that $Q=|A|$ then $W$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: But here rank$(A)=1$ and rank$(W)=2$, they are different.

Comment: In the new answer the ranks are equal.